# RiotControl Trigger action from multiple stores

Tags: javascript, event-handling, riot.js

I'm using [RiotJS](http://riotjs.com/) and [RiotControl](https://github.com/jimsparkman/RiotControl) in my application for components and event handling in a step based form journey. One of the form screens essentially collects data that goes to two stores. In old money I'd call this a multi-model view, and would handle this with a view model in something like Rails. The screen collects information on customer, and information on the actual journey, so two separate concerns sent to two different stores when the form is submitted.

```
// Store Examples

function customerDetails() {

  riot.observable(this);

  this.customer = {firstName: undefined, lastName: undefined}

  this.on('form-step:submitted', function(answers){
    this.customer.firstName = answers.firstName,
    this.customer.lastName = answers.lastName

    RiotControl.trigger('customerDetails:updated', this.customer);
  })
}

function surveyDetails() {

  riot.observable(this);

  this.survey = {questionOne: undefined, questionTwo: undefined}

  this.on('form-step:submitted', function(answers){
    this.survey.questionOne = answers.questionOne,
    this.survey.questionTwo = answers.questionTwo

    RiotControl.trigger('surveyDetails:updated', this.customer);
  })
}

// In main code

nextScreen.on('surveyDetails:updated customerDetails:updated', function(details){

  // I care about both of these events, but only want to execute 
  // this code once I've received the details from both stores. 

})
```

The next form screen requires information from both stores before rendering, so I'm struggling to see how I ensure that both update events from the two stores have been triggered, before mounting and rendering this screen, whilst maintaining the data from each store from the subsequent trigger of the event handler. Is something like this possible, or am I going about this in the wrong way?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Probably you will need the state of which step you currently are (I think a good place will be the parent of those components).

So for instance, customerDetails:updated will update the currentStep to 1, and then  surveyDetails:updated will update currentStep to 2. 
And then in your nextScreen.on, you check in which step you are, and move to the next step.